# How to sign a message with my https public key certificate?

Tags: ssl, x509certificate, sign, public-key

I just got myself an ssl certificate for my domain and it works fine, but I'm using the [bitcoin payment protocol](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0070.mediawiki) and I need to sign the messages with my public key before sending them but how are messages signed with an ssl certificate and what tools should I use?

**EDIT**

It seems what I actually need to do is sign a message using the public key of my ssl certificate issuer.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol specification must be incorrect. Digital signatures are signed with your private key.

Your certificate needs to *accompany* the message, and probably be included in the signature. Use the java.security.Signature class in association with your private key, possibly loaded from your KeyStore.

You may need to purchase a signing certificate: an SSL certificate may not be strong enough for bitcoin.

A signature using a public key is completely worthless. Anyone can do it. You sign with your private key. This is legally equivalent to your signature: only you can do it, and anyone can check it by verifying it with your public key, which is why the public key must accompany the signature; and at the same time they can establish whose signature it is, via the certificate which must also accompany the signature.

Or else bitcoin is radically insecure.

Comment: The reason I ask is because it is mentioned in the signing field description --> `digital signature over a hash of the protocol buffer serialized variation of the PaymentRequest message, with all fields serialized in numerical order (all current protocol buffer implementations serialize fields in numerical order) and signed using the` **public key** `in pki_data.` Also do you know of a library for python if possible please? :)

Comment: It's wrong. A signature using a public key is completely worthless. Anyone can do it. You sign with your private key. This is legally equivalent to your signature: only you can do it, and anyone can *check* it by verifying it with your public key, which is why the public key must accompany the signature; and at the same time they can establish *whose* signature it is, via the certificate which must also accompany the signature. I can't advise you about Python.

Comment: I have no doubt whatsoever about this. The wording should say 'private' instead of 'public'.

Comment: It seems that is the case. I could not bring myself to believe it initially though because it was referring to bitcoin, it's states 'public key' several times. I have pointed it out on github.

Answer (score -1):

Mystery solved, the message is to be signed using the bitcoin public key with the `signmessage "bitcoinaddress" "message"` bitcoin command.

Comment: Then the message is not signed, it will be encrypted. That's a difference!

Comment: It turns out this is not the correct answer after all because `digital signature over a hash of the protocol buffer serialized variation of the PaymentRequest message and signed using the ` **public key** `in pki_data.`